# If $A$ is path connected, then $\bar A$ is path connected?

Tags: general-topology

I know the topologist's sine curve serves as a counter example. But how do I show that $A = \{(x, \sin (1/x)): 0<x\le 1\}$ is path connected?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $(x_1,\sin(1/x_1))$ and $(x_2,\sin(1/x_2))$ are two points of $A$, then they can be connected by the path
$$\gamma(t)=\left(t,\sin\left(\frac1t\right)\right),\;t\in[x_1,x_2]$$

Answer (score 2):

Here's a hint. The continuous image of a path connected set is path connected, so you can try to find a relevant map.